# Young Measure, weak* convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the periodic extension of the function
\begin{equation}
h(x) := \begin{cases} 
a & 0 \leq x < \lambda \\
b & \lambda \leq x < 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and let $w_k : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be defined by
\begin{equation}
w_k(x) = h(kx)
\end{equation}
Show that
\begin{equation}
w_k \rightharpoonup^* \int^{1}_{0}{h(x) dx} = \lambda a + (1-\lambda) b \mbox{ in } L^{\infty}(0,1).
\end{equation}
So i choose $g \in L^1(0,1)$ arbitrarly and since $ \lambda \in (0,1)$ we get:
\begin{align}
            &\left| \int^{1}_{0}{g(x) w_k(x) dx} - \int^{1}_{0}{g(x)(\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b) dx} \right| = \left| \int^{1}_{0}{g(x) (w_k(x) - \lambda a  - (1-\lambda) b) dx} \right| \\
            &= \left| \int^{1}_{0}{g(x) (h(k x) - \lambda a  - (1-\lambda) b) dx} \right| \\
            &= \frac{1}{k} \left| \int^{k}_{0}{g(y/k) (h(y) - \lambda a - (1-\lambda) b)  dy} \right| \\
            &= \frac{1}{k} \left| \sum^{k-1}_{n=0}\left( \int^{1+n}_{\lambda + n}{g(y/k)(b - \lambda a - (1-\lambda)b) dy} + \int^{\lambda+n}_{n}{g(y/k)(a - \lambda a - (1-\lambda) b) dy} \right)\right| \\
            &=  \frac{1}{k} \left| \sum^{k-1}_{n=0}\left( \int^{1+n}_{\lambda + n}{g(y/k)( -\lambda a  + \lambda b) dy} + \int^{\lambda+n}_{n}{g(y/k)( (1 - \lambda) a - (1- \lambda) b) dy} \right)\right| \\
            &=  \frac{1}{k} \left| \sum^{k-1}_{n=0}\left( -\lambda(a-b)\int^{1+n}_{\lambda + n}{g(y/k) dy} + ( 1- \lambda) (a-b) \int^{\lambda+n}_{n}{g(y/k) dy} \right)\right| \\
            &= \frac{1}{k} \left| -\lambda (a-b)\int^{k}_{0}{g(y/k) dy}  + (a-b) \sum^{k-1}_{n=0} \int^{\lambda + n}_{n}{g(y/k) dy} \right| \\
            &=  \left| -\lambda (a-b)\int^{1}_{0}{g(x) dx}  + (a-b) \sum^{k-1}_{n=0} \int^{\frac{\lambda + n}{k}}_{\frac{n}{k}}{g(x) dx} \right| \\
            &=  \lambda |a-b| \left| \sum^{k-1}_{n=0} \int^{\frac{\lambda + n}{k \lambda }}_{\frac{n}{k \lambda}}{g(x \lambda ) dx} -\int^{1}_{0}{g(x) dx}  \right| \\
\end{align}
now I would say that for $k \rightarrow \infty$ the sum on the left in the last row convergeces to the right integral, since the intervals are getting smaller and stuff the missing parts of the interval to get $(0,1)$.

Now I am not sure if this is correct. I would be thankful if anyone can tell me if I am wrong or if I am missing something.

Comment: The $\lambda |a-b| \left| \sum^{k-1}_{n=0}\int^{\frac{1+n}{\lambda k}}_{\frac{\lambda + n}{k \lambda}}{g(\lambda z) dz} - \int^{1}_{0}{g(x) dx}\right|$ in the last line should be $\lambda |a-b| \left|\frac1\lambda  \sum^{k-1}_{n=0}\int^{\frac{1+n}{\lambda k}}_{\frac{\lambda + n}{k \lambda}}{g(\lambda z) dz} - \int^{1}_{0}{g(x) dx}\right|$

Comment: In the second last row I substitute $z = \frac{x}{\lambda}$ therefore $\lambda z = x$ with $\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.